# using multiprocessing for file reading in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have extremely large files. Each file is almost 2GB. Therefore, I would like to run multiple files in parallel. And I can do that because all of the files have similar format therefore, file reading can be done in parallel. I know I should use multiprocessing library but I am really confused how to use it with my code.

My code for file reading is:

```
def file_reading(file,num_of_sample,segsites,positions,snp_matrix):
    with open(file,buffering=2000009999) as f:
        ###I read file here. I am not putting that code here.
        try:
            assert len(snp_matrix) == len(positions)
            return positions,snp_matrix ## return statement
        except:
            print('length of snp matrix and length of position vector not the same.')
            sys.exit(1)
```

My main function is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    segsites = []
    positions = []
    snp_matrix = []




    path_to_directory = '/dataset/example/'
    extension = '*.msOut'

    num_of_samples = 162
    filename = glob.glob(path_to_directory+extension)

    ###How can I use multiprocessing with function file_reading
    number_of_workers = 10

   x,y,z = [],[],[]

    array_of_number_tuple = [(filename[file], segsites,positions,snp_matrix) for file in range(len(filename))]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(number_of_workers) as p:
        pos,snp = p.map(file_reading,array_of_number_tuple)
        x.extend(pos)
        y.extend(snp)
```

So my input to the function is as follows:

1. file - list containing filenames
2. num_of_samples - int value
3. segsites - initially an empty list to which I want to append as I am reading the file.
4. positions - initially an empty list to which I want to append as I am reading the file.
5. snp_matrix - initially an empty list to which I want to append as I am reading the file.

The function returns positions list and snp_matrix list at the end. How can I use multiprocessing for this where my arguments are lists and integer? The way I've used multiprocessing gives me following error:

**TypeError: file_reading() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'segsites', 'positions', and 'snp_matrix'**

Comment: For the future, might help to read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which (I think the question changed now quite a lot from the initial one - even though you might have wanted to ask the same thing, what was written was a bit different). So I deleted my answer as it does not make sense now...

Comment: Also, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to make your questions as close to what is described there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in the list that is being passed to the Pool.map are not automatically unpacked. You can generally only have one argument in your 'file_reading' function.

Of course, this argument can be a tuple, so it is no problem to unpack it yourself:

```
def file_reading(args):
    file, num_of_sample, segsites, positions, snp_matrix = args
    with open(file,buffering=2000009999) as f:
        ###I read file here. I am not putting that code here.
        try:
            assert len(snp_matrix) == len(positions)
            return positions,snp_matrix ## return statement
        except:
             print('length of snp matrix and length of position vector not the same.')
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    segsites = []
    positions = []
    snp_matrix = []

    path_to_directory = '/dataset/example/'
    extension = '*.msOut'

    num_of_samples = 162
    filename = glob.glob(path_to_directory+extension)

    number_of_workers = 10

    x,y,z = [],[],[]


    array_of_number_tuple = [(filename[file], num_of_samples, segsites,positions,snp_matrix) for file in range(len(filename))]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(number_of_workers) as p:
        pos,snp = p.map(file_reading,array_of_number_tuple)
        x.extend(pos)
        y.extend(snp)
```